# LINQ to EF (Entify Framework) does not create partial methods "OnColumnChanged"

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, linq-to-entities, mvvm-light

I have created a LINQ to EF model (to be used as the model in an mvvm wpf application) but the classes for each table do not contain on[columnname]changed or on[columnname]changing methods.  I thought these were auto generated by the framework.  I wanted to add to some of my own public partial methods in order to create some data validation as shown in the following page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/07/07/implementing-validation-in-wpf-on-entity-framework-entities.aspx

The following class is an example of the auto generated code from EF.

```
 Imports System
 Imports System.Collections.Generic

Partial Public Class client
Public Property idClient As Integer
Public Property chrFirst As String
Public Property chrLast As String
Public Property chrCompany As String
Public Property chrEmail As String
Public Property chrPhone1 As String
Public Property chrPhone1Ext As String
Public Property chrPhone2 As String
Public Property chrPhone2Ext As String
Public Property chrFax As String
Public Property chrSuite As String
Public Property chrAddess As String
Public Property chrCity As String
Public Property chrProvince As String
Public Property chrCountry As String
Public Property chrPostal As String
Public Property dtCreated As Nullable(Of Date)
Public Property dtUpdated As Nullable(Of Date)
Public Property FTC_Type As Nullable(Of Byte)

Public Overridable Property invoices As ICollection(Of invoice) = New HashSet(Of invoice)
Public Overridable Property jobs As ICollection(Of job) = New HashSet(Of job)

 End Class
```

When I add a partial public class of the same name I can see all the declarations of the original class generated by the EF in the declarations dropdown in the upper right hand corner fo the window in visual studio.

1- Does LINQ to EF work this way?
2- I am using vb.net 4 and visual studio 2012, is there another way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

which template are you using to generate the files?

The [Self Tracking Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff407090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are best-suited for use in a client/server WPF application, because they implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and allow for disconnected (n-tier) change tracking.

Comment: I am not sure what template I am using.  I have a db on a sql 2008 express server.  I added a new "item" to the project and chose ado.net entity data model.  From there I just followed the wizard to create the connection and selected all db objects.  I am using wpf to create client/server application, or trying to anyway.

Comment: Then you're probably using the default EF template, which is not the one I mentioned. I suggest you read the link I provided, it will surely help you out, as STEs are much better for Client/Server and also for WPF because they support two-way databinding.

Comment: I am using vb.net, and had to find the STE framework extension and install it.  Once I did that I had to delete the existing model.tt and model.context.tt files and right click in the model designer and click add code generated item.  Then I chose the self tracking entity extension and it recreated the .tt files with the current model name.  That added the onpropertychanged functions that I wanted to use for data validation.  The article posted has instructions on how to accomplish all of this.